# How to pass the value return from javascript from view to controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Here is my code, in "View" I wrote like this :

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){
        console.log($('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
          //alert(this.value);
          return this.value;
        }).get().join(', '));
    }) ;
});
```

I should pass the returned value from this javascript to the controller file.

How can I do this please someone help me...

Comment: To which controller or controller's method you want to send value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ajax` request to send values you want :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){
      var value_to_send = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
          return this.value;
      }).get().join(', '));

      $.get('route_to_your_action', {value_name: value_to_send},function(data)           {
          //data contain response from controller action
          alert(data);
      })
  });
});
```

In the other side inside contoller you could get the value passe using `Input` :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
.
.
.
function postHotelresults(){
    $value_name = Input::get('value_name');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would like use the "value_to_send" in my Controller function named as postHotelresults()...                                                                                   By using this                                                                            $.get('route_to_your_action', {value_name: value_to_send},function(data)           {
          
      })                                                                                                        How can I pass it

Comment: Already passed in `{value_name: value_to_send}` you could get it in the controller by name `value_name` e.g : `Input::get('value_name')`.

Comment: I'm trying to print that value in controller but it didn't print any values..  What should I give instead of ""route_to_your_action"" my URL is ""hotel/hotelresults"" and my Controller name is ""HotelController""  inside this I need to access this value in the function named as ""postHotelresults""

Comment: You could not print it in controller, you could store it somewhere or use it for some operation, and you could return it to javascript callback and show it (check my updated answer).

Comment: What should I give instead of ""route_to_your_action"" Whether use the function name or url

Comment: You should add new route for your action in route.php file as `Route::get('route_to_your_action', 'HotelController@postHotelresults');`.

Comment: You may also find you need a backslash before your route depending on how web.php is set up: `$.get('route_to_your_action', ` might need to be `$.get('/route_to_your_action', `